# Buscar elementos de una lista en otra prolog

Tags: prolog

Buenas estoy trabajando en un recomendador de medicinas en el que tengo una lista de medicamentos y otra con alergias, un hecho contiene(medicamento, componente) donde X medicamento contiene a Y componente y otro que es tiene_alergia(paciente, componente_alérgico) donde X es alérgico a Y componente. Lo que quiero es sacar la lista de medicamentos que no contienen ese medicamento pero no lo consigo. Ejemplo:

```
Tiene_alergia(Pepe, amoxicilina).
Tiene_alergia(pepe, ampicilina).

Contiene(clamoxil, amoxicilina).
Contiene(britapen, ampicilina).
```

Ahora mediante `findall` obtengo 2 listas A = lista de alergias del paciente y L = lista de componentes de los medicamentos.

Llamo a la regla eliminar(A, L, L2).
L2 será la lista después del filtrado.

```
Eliminar([],[]).
Eliminar(X, [Y|Ys], L2) :- posicion(X, [Y|Ys],Pos), borrar(Pos, [Y|Ys], L2).
Eliminar([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], L2):- eliminar(X, [Y|Ys]) ; eliminar(Xs, Ys).

Posicion(E, [E, _], 0).
Posicion(E,[_|C], P):- posición (E,C,P1), P is P1+1.

Borrar(I, L, L2) :- insertar(_,I,L2,L).
Insertar(X, 0, L2, [X|L2]).
Insertar(X, Pos, [C|R], [C|R2]) :- Pos1 is Pos -1, insertar(X, pos1, R, R2).
```

La cosa es que si yo llamo a

```
 eliminar([amoxicilina,ampicilina],[amoxicilina, ampicilina], L2).
```

`L2 = [ampicilina];` y esto es erróneo debería ser `[]`

Habría alguna forma de corregirlo?

Gracias de ante mano.

Comment: Espeo esto te ayude, https://pastebin.com/Wef1Asq3 no lo pongo como respuesta porque aún tengo mis dudas

Comment: Voy a probarlo, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Si no entendí mal, el predicado eliminar/2 elimina cada elemento de la lista A de la lista L. Para esto puedes utilizar el predicado [subtract/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=subtract/3) con la forma:

```
subtract(L, A, L2).
```

Por ejemplo:

```
?- subtract([amoxicilina,ampicilina],[amoxicilina, ampicilina], L2).
L2 = [].

?- subtract([amoxicilina,ampicilina,componenteAux1, componenteAux2], 
[amoxicilina, ampicilina], L2).
L2 = [componenteAux1, componenteAux2].
```

Ahora, creo que la representación que estás usando para los hechos puede ser un poco mejor, por ejemplo, si consideras representar el hecho contiene/2 de la siguiente forma:

```
contiene(medicamento,[lista de componentes de medicamento]).
```

sería un poco más claro y directo trabajar sobre ese hecho.

Sin embargo, y teniendo en cuenta la definición de tus hechos, puedes definir los siguientes predicados:

```
alergias(Paciente, Alergias):-
 findall(ComponenteAlergico, tiene_alergia(Paciente, ComponenteAlergico), 
 Alergias).

medicamentos(Paciente, MedicamentosAptos):-
 findall(Medicamento,contiene(Medicamento, _), ListaMedicamentos), 
 list_to_set(ListaMedicamentos, Medicamentos),
 getMedicamentosComponentes(Medicamentos, MedicamentosComponentes),
 alergias(Paciente, Alergias),
 getMedicamentosAptos(Alergias, MedicamentosComponentes, 
 MedicamentosAptos).


getMedicamentosComponentes([],[]).
getMedicamentosComponentes([H|B],[[H,Componentes]|R]):-
 findall(Componente, contiene(H, Componente), Componentes),
 getMedicamentosComponentes(B,R).


getMedicamentosAptos(_,[],[]).
getMedicamentosAptos(Alergias, [[Medicamento,Componentes]|Medicamentos], 
[Medicamento|R]):-
 subtract(Componentes, Alergias, Resultado),
 Resultado = Componentes,
 getMedicamentosAptos(Alergias, Medicamentos, R).

getMedicamentosAptos(Alergias, [[Medicamento,Componentes]|Medicamentos], 
R):-
 getMedicamentosAptos(Alergias, Medicamentos, R).
```

El predicado getMedicamentosComponentes/2 arma la lista [[medicamento, [componentes]], [medicamento, [componentes]], ...]. El predicado getMedicamentosAptos/3 toma como entrada una lista de alergias, la lista de medicamentos del predicado getMedicamentosComponentes/2 y retorna una lista con los medicamentos cuyos componentes no contiene ningún componente de la lista de alergias. Por último, el predicado medicamentos/2 toma como entrada un paciente Paciente y retorna una lista de MedicamentosAptos de medicamentos aptos para ese paciente.